# how the opcode cache actually works?

Tags: php, performance, caching, eaccelerator

im doing my final project and its about optimizing web performance (focus on caching).
i plan to use eaccelearator as a tool in my final project.
i need to know the background process of it, the flow diagram about how it works and how an opcode cache can boost performance of websites.
it can be eaccelerator, or anykind of opcode cache.
is anyone know about it? or any opcode cache that have complete documentation?

a lot of thanks.. need the answer soon.

Answer (score 7):

There is some very technical documentation about APC (an eAccelerator alternative) located here: 
http://cvs.php.net/viewvc.cgi/pecl/apc/TECHNOTES.txt?view=co

The basic idea is to cache the compiled code and then run the compiled code instead of having to re-compile each time. i.e. generally when you visit a PHP script in your web browser, PHP has to compile the code, and then execute it. The opcode cache instead caches the compiled version of the code so that it only needs to be executed when you visit the script in the browser.

Comment: Due to the change in PHP repo, the new link to the technote is http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/apc/trunk/TECHNOTES.txt?view=co